# Client Access AS400 Java wrapper

Tags: java, session, ibm-midrange, simulate

Is there free/non-free `Client Access` Java bases wrapper that can simulating End-User typing into `Client Access Session`

- login with popup Dialog/Window for UserName & PassWord
- moving to the column & row `from the input file`
- typing chars to the session `from the input file`
- copy warning (column & row & lenght) `to the output file`
- test if (column & row & lenght) contains some Text `from the input file`
- waiting required time `from the input file`
- reporting `to the output file`
- logOff `from the input file`
- reset & restart session after logOff `from the input file`

similair funcionalities as for example by using `AutoIt`,

Comment: Why not just use AutoIt?

Comment: @John Y this process is managed from Java code, then is more confortable use original Java Client Access Session API as calling whatever (sure nothing wrong with AutoIt), I'm able to write that, but if/maybe there this code exists, then why reinvent the wheel :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind doing some java hacking ... you could take a look at the [TN5250J](http://tn5250j.sourceforge.net/) project for information on how to interact with the 5250 data stream.

This isn't going to give you routines to directly control a session ... but you might be able to adapt some of the code to your own purposes.

Comment: thanks for info, I found live funcionalities on the API server for this library, now in the testing processes, data are sent to the MQ server, I think that this way is more safiest as simulating user input (I found one written in C++, but sometimes don't want to end and gone from WinOS memory) +1 for info